# Advice/Experiences, Auto Insurance, Florida, 18 years old

Tags: united-states, car, car-insurance, florida, rates

I am in Florida, United States. I have recently bought a reliable (however temporary) 2004 Chevrolet Colorado (rear wheel drive, maroon colored pickup truck). I have done a lot of research but I'm looking for advice/personal experiences with finding cheap insurance companies. I also wanted to know discounts for insurance companies.

- I am 18 (19 soon), however I got licensed at 17 and I am still a student.
- to and from work is roughly 10 miles a day, 70 a week, 280 a month (minimum
  driving) and I have a full time job
  (Processing/Packaging/Distributing Frozen Foods).
- I am also a defensive driver (Snapshot or safe drivers discount tool
  is preferred). I have a squeaky clean driving and criminal record.
- I've had a previous policy with Direct I closed because previous car issues.

What would be the best way to find cheap insurance for someone in my situation?

Comment: Does Florida require auto insurance?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Even if it wouldn't: Would it be wise not to have it?

Comment: The question says: "I drive 70 miles a week...I've had insurance more than a year ago, don't currently have it." So if those statements are true, then the answer is stop driving and get insurance today"

Comment: also "10 miles a day, 70 a week, 2,100 a month" has a math problem. 2,100 a month is 70 a day. so it is either "70 a day, 2,100 a month" or "70 a week, about 300 a month"

Comment: Yes State Law requires insurance

Comment: Ahhh. The first one of the day. Thank you for keeping me on my toes Mr. Formal.

Comment: Oof. I'm sorry. I got off a 12 hour shift and wrote this. (Minimum Driving) 10 miles a day = 70 miles a week = Roughly 280 a month. (Wow math was seriously incorrect) Noted. Not good at math after a long night.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are currently driving and don't have insurance. You need to get insurance today. It appears that it is law in Florida that all drivers must have insurance. Even if it wasn't the law, you still should get insurance to protect you in case of an accident.

Because you need insurance today, you need to worry less about getting the lowest rate, you need to get reputable insurance now. Take the time to contact three well known insurance companies in your state and get a quote. Don't use the website, or a central number, call the agents office nearest you. You can use the website to find the closest agent, but going though the website to get a quote might slow things down.

They will want to know about you, the car, the approximate mileage per month or per year, and your driving record. The biggest things that will influence your rate is your age, your driving record and where you live. The agent will know the minimum numbers for the insurance as required by the state. There may be things that the state requires be included so make sure that you get a quote that covers everything required. If you do pick any optional coverage be consistent with all the companies. Then pick the lowest priced one.

Sometimes the company your parent has can be the cheapest option. They will sometimes give a discount as if you were a longtime customer instead of a new customer. Speaking of discounts, you can get a discount for being a good student. They will want to see a transcript/report card.

If you can afford to pay for a six month or year policy do so, it can be cheaper. But don't worry that picking to pay a lump sum locks you in. If you find a better rate before the term ends, when you cancel the policy early they will refund the coverage for any unused days.

Once you get insurance today you can take the time to research the customer service and rates for other insurance companies. The switch if you can get a better rate for good customer service.

Comment: There we go I fixed the questions haha. I can answer all their questions before they ask me at this point. I'm wanting a 12 month bare minimum coverage policy without financing. My reasoning for asking here was to see if anybody has done this before in Florida, and has a certain app, or just additional discounts I'm not sure about. I listed the information for the ones I am eligible for. (To a certain extent)